# RPi.GPIO add_event_detect are sometimes ignored

Tags: python, gpio, raspberry-pi4

I'm working on a project that is using GPIO(BCM) 17, 27, 22, 5 and 6.

Events on pin 17 are detected pretty well, but GPIO 27 is really reluctant to trigger events. they seems to get detected with a bit of delay...

I'm using a RPI4 with buster lite.

This is a video showing the issue

https://youtu.be/bLXQkA1bzKA

there is a photo of the [wiring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XGoN.jpg)

This is the snippet that I'm using in the video in python3

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def my_callback(channel):
        print("event!")
GPIO.add_event_detect(27, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=300)

while True:
    pass
```

Is there any better methods to detect button press? are there GPIO that must be avoided in the RaspberryPi platform ? Or maybe I'm doing something completely wrong...?

Comment: I had another Pi4 laying around, should have tried this first, and with this one GPIO27 is more reliable, this isn't like the GPIO events that I'm used to since I'm usually doing my project using Arduino boards, but this is definitely better than the first pi... Could it be that my pi is somewhat defective? (I used the same SD card and same PSU (official USB C power supply))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already had a Pi with some strange IO behaviour. It was from the early batch of the Pi4. Keep in mind that Raspberry Pi are really cheaply made and even the slightest noise in the PSU or just bad luck in the silicon lottery can make the Pi an unreliable device. Just to be sure, swap the PSU (even if it's an official one) and if this doesn't solve the problem just ask for an RMA to your provider.

Comment: Thanks I'll return the unit since it's working fine with the other Raspberry Pi 4... I can't believe how unreliable those devices are... Never saw that with any other of my microcontrollers based projects...

Answer (score 0):

You have set the bounce time to 300 ms, which is quite long. Try 30 ms, then your program will react much more reliably.

The event is called only if there is a change in the signal after the bounce time (in your case 300 ms).

---

Also please try:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

def my_callback(channel):
    print("event!")

GPIO.add_event_detect(27, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=300)

while True:
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Some strange behavior is caused by the load of a loop without content.

Comment: thanks you very much for your help, I tried many different timing with no difference at all... there is a  [video](https://youtu.be/t5v-9MoM6wU) with the same old Pi4 with a bounce time of 30ms

Comment: there is [another video](https://youtu.be/Ce7VPkXPn8s) showing you the exact same code but running on another Pi4, the result is really different I have double event with this one and I no events seems to be ignored... This is the exact same SD card / power supply.

Comment: Adding the `time.sleep(0.01)` seems to make things worst... Please see the results [here](https://youtu.be/9-CJlQNp9Fs)

Answer (score 0):

Look you guys. bouncetime does not work the way you want. As soon as the event is triggered weather it be a button press or noise the bouncetime starts.
So by setting a high bouncetime you may be waiting longer than the button press.

You need a short hardware bouncetime like 1 or 5 and then do a double software debounce. Something like....

```
    time.sleep(.060)
    if not GPIO.input(pin):
            time.sleep(.060)
            if not GPIO.input(pin):
                        A button was really pushed.
```

All in .125 seconds. 5 hardware bouncetime + 2 .06 second = .125
Which is about the time the button was in contact.

This makes sure the button is still off which is pressed in a pull up button.

Also note. I like to remove the event detect at the beginning of the handler. Then adding a 2 second sleep. Then turn the event detect back on.
This keep from doube presses.

In your case

```
           GPIO.remove_event_detect(27)
```

I hope I help someone in the future as this was a hard lesson to learn.
You think buttons are simple.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).